# Stop timer on button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, timer, onclick

I'm working on an application and I have a timer with the current date, hour, minutes and seconds displayed. It is incremented every second. What I want to do is to stop the timer on a button click, but I'm not sure why the clearInterval() function doesn't work. My code is:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           timer: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //current time
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                currentTime : new Date().toLocaleString()
            })
        }, 1000)
    }


   stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(this.state.currentTime)
  }

   render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <h4>Current time: {this.state.currentTime}</h4>
                    <Button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop timer</Button>
                </div>
              )
   }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setInterval in a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299174/setinterval-in-a-react-app)

Answer (score 6):

`setInterval()` result is the `intervalID` and you should use this for `clearInterval()`.

```
this.state = {
  ...
  intervalId: ""
};

...

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
   ...
}, 1000);
this.setState({ intervalId });

...

clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the clearInterval on wrong variable . You should do this.

I'm working on an application and I have a timer with the current date, hour, minutes and seconds displayed. It is incremented every second. What I want to do is to stop the timer on a button click, but I'm not sure why the clearInterval() function doesn't work. My code is:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           timer: "",
           intervalId: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //current time
       const intervalId =  setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                currentTime : new Date().toLocaleString()
            })
        }, 1000); 

     this.setState({intervalId})
    }


   stopTimer = () => {
     if (this.state.intervalId) {
       clearInterval(this.state.intervelId)
     }
  }

   render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <h4>Current time: {this.state.currentTime}</h4>
                    <Button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop timer</Button>
                </div>
              )
   }

}
```