# How access object which created interval from interval callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to JavaScript and coming not forth with my current issue.
I have here an React App and I try to expand it by a timer functionality. I created a timer (similar to this question: [setInterval in a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299174/setinterval-in-a-react-app)) and the timer functionality itself is working.

But the timer callback (or more exactly the `setInterval` callback) is not working. In the `setInterval` the variable `this` is pointing to `Windows` but I thought it should point to `App`, which is the class/object who created the timer and contains the `setInterval` callback. Therefore I get following error.

[image]

Here are the crucial code changes I made:

```
class App extends Component {

  //...

  componentDidMount() {

    //...

    var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 5000);
    // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
    this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    
    //...

    // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }

  timer() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
      this.requestDeviceStatus(this.state.whitelist[i]);
    }
  }

 //...

}
```

But you can access the complete source code/commit here:
https://github.com/wewa00/Reacticz/blob/backgroundtimer/src/App.js,
(And this are the Relevant commits: [02e3e93](https://github.com/wewa00/Reacticz/commit/02e3e93b6dbd645638629155ff8d0366a0496ea1), [6bcabba](https://github.com/wewa00/Reacticz/commit/6bcabba5ac02ed1cb7a36ad41f8f6eae5f61a804).)

Why `this` pointing to `Window` and how can I access `App` from within `timer()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TypeError**

Use timer function with ES6 arrow method.

```
timer=()=>{
   for (let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
        this.requestDeviceStatus(this.state.whitelist[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that hint. You were really fast with your answer. I had a mistake and corrected this like you stated. But the issue is still here, as you can see in the updated question.

Comment: check my updated answer. why i suggest `=>` instead of bind. we no need have remember to put bind each function inside the constructor. it something crowd in constructor

Comment: I did not really understand this. But with your suggestion `this: App` in the `Scope` of `timer()`.

Comment: `this` target the class scope. if you are using `time()` like without `bind(this)` like @Prime answer. `this` will may not working. for same if you using `ES6` method like `=>` function its will allow parent scope this inside the `timer()` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bind` to access `App` inside `timer` function.

```
class App extends Component {

  //...

  componentDidMount() {

    //...

    var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 5000);
    // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
    this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this); // <------------------------------
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    
    //...

    // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }

  timer() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.whitelist.length; i++) {
      this.requestDeviceStatus(this.state.whitelist[i]);
    }
  }

 //...

}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but I still get the same error message. And when I debug my app, I can see, that `this: Window` in the `Scope` of  `timer()`.