# where call setInterval in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I want to create a counter using setState and setInterval.
I don't want to put react.dom render in an interval because I know it's not a good-practice.
This is my effort so far:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  increment = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter+1});
    }, 1000);
   
  };
  
  render() {
    return <div>
    <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
    </div>;
  }
}


const el = <Counter />; 
ReactDOM.render(
  el, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have also try it this way:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
     counter: this.state.counter+1});
  };
  
  render() {
    return <div>
    <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
    </div>;
  }
}

setInterval(Counter.increment, 100)

const el = <Counter />; 
ReactDOM.render(
  el, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

None of them worked.
What is the problem?

Comment: Just wondering what errors you got?

Comment: No errors! It only shows 0

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299174/setinterval-in-a-react-app

Comment: @nfn Better to use previous state while setting the counter: `this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: prevState.counter+1
  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `increment` function.  You have to call it, inside `componentDidMount()`.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  increment = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter+1});
    }, 1000);
   
  };
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.increment();
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
    <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @nfn please check this answer.