# React, setInterval not working properly, h1 element not being updated correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a simple React app that upadates a h1 element every second with setInterval function. I have an array with strings and every second I want randomly pick a string from that array and uses that string inside h1. But my code doesn't work properly. h1 is not being updated every second but every millisecond.

```
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo.js'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const myPersonalInfo = ['books', 'music', 'code']; 
  const [state, changeState] = useState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);

  setInterval(() => {
    changeState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PersonalInfo title={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
function PersonalInfo({ title}) {
    return <div>
        <h1>I Love {title} </h1>
    </div>
}

export default PersonalInfo
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299174/setinterval-in-a-react-app

Comment: you are creating a new 'setInterval' on every render - check link above

Comment: you create setInterval in global object every time of repaint component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo.js'
    import { useState } from 'react';
    
    function App() {
      const myPersonalInfo = ['books', 'music', 'code']; 
      const [state, changeState] = useState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
         setInterval(() => {
            changeState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
         }, 2000);
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <PersonalInfo title={state} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Use useEffect hook

Answer (score 2):

Use react useEffect

useEffect with empty dependency only run on first render

[clear interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) on component unmount

```js
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo.js'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const myPersonalInfo = ['books', 'music', 'code']; 
  const [state, changeState] = useState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      changeState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
    }, 2000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PersonalInfo title={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would wanna use `useEffect` with an empty dependencies array, to ensure that the code for setting the interval runs only once on mount, as otherwise you create in memory a new interval on every state changes. Also you wanna clear that interval on unmount.

Also, you can use a function to update the state, as otherwise, you will register in memory a set interval that will keep updating the state with the same value, the first random one. The state updater function ensures you hydrate the interval with a new value evrytime.

```js
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo.js'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const myPersonalInfo = ['books', 'music', 'code']; 
  const [state, changeState] = useState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);

  
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   const id = setInterval(() => {
       changeState(prev => myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
    }, 2000);
    
    // clear the interval before the component gets unmounted
    return ()=>clearInterval(id);
  
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PersonalInfo title={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect and set state as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    changeState(myPersonalInfo[Math.floor(Math.random() * myPersonalInfo.length)]);
  }, 2000);
}}, [state])
```