# Update state in setInterval not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm new to react, today I encounter a very strange case, what I want todo is to get the data from server side every 5 seconds, but it doesn't work as expected, the problem can be simplied to this:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

edit the `App.js`

```js
import { useState } from "react";


function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const increment = () => {
    // simulate the querying, for example, checking the status of server
    console.log('Current count value:', count)
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  setInterval(increment, 1000)


  return (
    <span>Count: {count}</span>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to update the state `count` every 1s, and I think the output in console would be

```
Current count value: 0
Current count value: 1
Current count value: 2
...
```

However, the output is very strange, click the link to see the output
(I cant' insert image in the content)

[chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7KDr.png)

Thanks

Comment: You are not using setInterval, the right way in React. You must be careful about the async operations flow. Here is a thread to read about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299174/setinterval-in-a-react-app

Comment: Take reference from here. You simply need to update `count` value based on prev `count` value.

Comment: Also, one point since you are new to React, the `useEffect` will fire twice in development mode for some reason.

Comment: see the react documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @RukshanJS thank you,  I found the problem: every time the `count` update, the `setInterval(increment, 1000)` will be trigger 1 time (because of the re-rendering). So in the first time, there in only 1 `setInterval` is running, after the `count` updated, another `setInterval` will be created, ... so there maybe many `setInterval` is running...

Answer (score 0):

You need to start interval in `useEffect` and clear when component unmount

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const increment = () => {
      // simulate the querying, for example, checking the status of server
      console.log('Current count value:', count)
      setCount(prev => prev + 1) // You can't use count state because it's will trigger useEffect and cause infinite loop. You need to use callback to update from previous value
    }

    const intervalId = setInterval(increment, 1000) // setInterval return interval id

    return () => {
      // Clear interval using intervalId
      // This function run when component unmount
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <span>Count: {count}</span>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` instead [setinterval-is-moderately-evil](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/setinterval-is-moderately-evil)

```
const DURATION = 1000;
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, DURATION);
});
```

You can read more of how to use `setInterval` in react here [making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked exactly as what I expected. I don't need an `setInterval` because every time the `count` updated, the callback in `useEffect` will be called by default (because the `deps` of `useEffect` is not set, by default it will be called every time the state updated). And I also found that if I set the `deps` of `useEffect` to `[]`, it will not work because the callback will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect` hook to keep track of changes in the component's states.

trying to invoke a function inside the body of your component will make that function to re-invoke everytime any DOM is updated. The best practice to initiate your component is to put it inside a `useEffect` hook **without** dependencies.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(increment, 1000)
}, []);
```

Now if you want to keep track of a state when it's updated you can use anotther useEffect and add the state in **dependency array**. Like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('incremented', count)
}, [count]);
```

Here is an edited version of your code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    // a function that changes count state
    const increment = () => {
        setCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }

    // when component is mounted
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(increment, 1000)
    }, []);

    // when count state changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('incremented', count)
    }, [count]);

    return (
        <span>Count: {count}</span>
    );
}

export default App;
```